# Cookie expiration only working for session cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm setting a cookie but the problem is that when I look at the expiration date in the Chrome inspector, it's only showing as a session cookie. This is my code:

```
var ExpirationDate = new Date();
ExpirationDate.setDate(ExpirationDate.getDate() + 400);
document.cookie = 'eucookie=2;' + ExpirationDate.toUTCString();
```

What do I need to change to make it expire in 13 months (400 days) instead of at the end of the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it that it's the `expires` property you're setting:

```
document.cookie = 'eucookie=2;expires=' + ExpirationDate.toUTCString();
```